# Can I find to what target .NET dll was built looking into the file?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, assemblies, .net-4.0

I have a bit of mess with projects coming some on 4.0 some on 3.5

Is it possible to find out what version of .NET was the dll built looking into the file (not from code!) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [ildasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(VS.80).aspx):

```
ildasm assembly.dll
```

Then double click on MANIFEST and look at the version:

- Metadata version: v4.0.30319 (CLR 4.0, meaning .NET 4.0)
- Metadata version: v2.0.50727 (CLR 2.0, meaning .NET 2.0 to .NET 3.5)

Comment: 4.0.30319 can mean 4.5. 
2.0.50727 can mean up to 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Ildasm (comes with VS) can show you what version of the framework DLLs it's referencing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a programmatic solution,then just load the dll into Assembly and check the ImageRuntimeversion

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.imageruntimeversion.aspx